# Purchase Order Workflow..Openerp7

Tags: openerp-7, odoo

As seen in Odoo 7.0, We have states on right sides i.e. Draft PO, RFQ Sent, Purchase Order, and Done. I want to have Approve state along with the button on top and state must be between Draft PO and RFQ Sent

Please guide how can I have it

Thanks

Comment: Yes I have done it but it does not approve. It directly makes draft PO to a PO...

Comment: Create purchase order with 10000 amount and you will see approve botton default amount is 5000 so you need to create PO amont > 5000.

Comment: Thx a lot 

your are right but is this per client? I mean we are never limited to amount but the levels right? So up till how much levels odoo allows approvals? any idea? Please guide and tell where can i see dat from

Thanks

Comment: You may go to follow path `Setting => Configuration => Purchases => Purchase Order : limit to require a second approval (this field)` you can handle amount via this. Thanks

Comment: Thx dear this is what i have seen But this is amount i.e. Money I am not concerned with money I am concerned with how many total appprovals can I have in Odoo? Like 100 1000 20 000 etc

Comment: Oh Thanks so much.. and can you please tell how can I make a checkbox in openerp interface?not programming?